# jQuery: Replace multiple regex matches with string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use this block of code to replace ALL "123"'s in a long string with a different number.

```
   var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    $('#food').after(
      "<div id='123' name='123'> etc etc".replace('123', new_id)
    );
```

But it's only replacing the first 123 with the new_id. Is there a way to replace all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make it a regex instead of a plain vanilla string and add the `/g` flag.

```
"<div id='123' name='123'> etc etc".replace(/123/g, new_id)
```

Answer (score 5):

`replace(/123/g, new_id)`

This is [regex literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions) with a global (`g`) flag.